# Why does Blowfish::PP's encrypt only print five characters?

Tags: perl, encryption, blowfish

Good day! 
I have a code here that uses the `blowfish_PP` algorithm from [Crypt::Blowfish_PP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-Blowfish_PP) to encrypt a password.

I've provided a sample "key" variable for a start (though
I will make a function later that will increment key every time I
use it), but for now this is what I've got:

```
use Crypt::Blowfish_PP;

$key = "12345678";
$$plaintextBlock = "mystringhere";

$blowfish=new Crypt::Blowfish_PP($key);

$ciphertextBlock=$blowfish->encrypt($plaintextBlock);

$plaintextBlock=$blowfish->decrypt($ciphertextBlock);

print "\n";
print $ciphertextBlock."\n";
print $plaintextBlock."\n";
```

This `$ciphertextBlock` outputs ONLY 5 characters.
When I checked the `encryptedpassword` of other DB using MD5, it contains
several characters. Why is that? What is inside
`encrypt()` and `decrypt()` functions? Does the "key" value matters
on how long the encrypted password will be?

Answers will be much appreciated. =)

Answer (score 3):

According to [Blowfish_PP documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~mattbm/Crypt-Blowfish_PP-1.12/Blowfish_PP.pm), `encrypt` and `decrypt` only work on single 8-byte block at a time. So if you are encrypting longer strings, you need to call `encrypt` repeatedly.

Why it only outputs 5 "characters" is probably because the ciphertext contains non-printable characters. If you want to print the data, convert it to e.g. hex ascii first:

```
print sprintf("%02x"x8, unpack("C8", $ciphertextBlock)), "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

As laalto said, Blowfish_PP (because it's Blowfish, not because it's _PP) is working on blocks.

Dealing with it is usually complex, that's why you have [Crypt::CBC](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Crypt::CBC) module which is a wrapper on (virtually) any Crypt::* module that provides block cipher, and allows you to use it in a much simpler way.

For example, your code with Crypt::CBC would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Crypt::CBC;

my $key = "12345678";
my $plaintextBlock = "mystringhere";

my $cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(
    -key    => $key,
    -cipher => 'Blowfish_PP'
);

my $ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($plaintextBlock);
# my $textual = $ciphertext;
# $textual =~ s/([^a-zA-Z0-9])/sprintf "\\x%02x", ord $1/ge;
# print "ciphertext: [$textual]\n";
print "ciphertext: [$ciphertext]\n";

my $plaintext  = $cipher->decrypt($ciphertext);
print "plaintext: [$plaintext]\n";
```

Remember that ciphertext is stream of bytes, so it's not really printable. You might want to unhash 3 lines in the code (starting with my $textual = $ciphertext) to show the ciphertext in a bit more readable way.

Additional benefit of using Crypt::CBC is that if you'll ever want to switch to another algorithm - it's just one change in Crypt::CBC->new() call.

By the way - why Crypt::Blowfish_PP ? I mean, why not Crypt::Blowfish?  _PP version is generally simply slower.

Additional note, straight from [Crypt::Blowfish](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Crypt::Blowfish), which we can assume to be functionally equivalent to Crypt::Blowfish_PP:

> The module is capable of being used
>   with Crypt::CBC.  You’re encouraged to
>   read the perldoc for Crypt::CBC if you
>   intend to use this module for Cipher
>   Block Chaining modes.  In fact, if you
>   have any intentions of encrypting more
>   than eight bytes of data with this, or
>   any other block cipher, you’re going
>   to need some type of block chaining
>   help.  Crypt::CBC tends to be very
>   good at this. If you’re not going to
>   encrypt more than eight bytes, your
>   data must be exactly eight bytes long.
>   If need be, do your own padding. "\0"
>   as a null byte is perfectly valid to
>   use for this.

Answer (score 2):

change $$plaintextBlock to $plaintextBlock, it will work for the 1st 8 bytes.